# how can we make text-cursor start ahead in fields (textarea in this case) than its default starting position using html and css

Tags: html, css

In this image, the text-cursor in textarea field is behind the placeholder, the placeholder has intentionally been placed ahead to match the symmetry of other input fields, but i want the text-cursor to also start from the placeholder's starting point
[image]

Here we see that the placeholder is ahead and also the write-cursor starts ahead, i have used bootstrap and this is happening by default. So i wanted to match this very same thing in the text-area as well ie placeholder is a little further from the input field and the text-cursor also starts from there(The beginning of placeholder).
[image]

Comment: I see no difference between these two images...

Comment: the text-cursor's starting point. In "enter your first name" the cursor is with the placehoders "E". 
Whereas in text area there is a small gap between the placeholders "E" and the text-cursor,
i wanted that in textarea as well the text-cursor starts ahead sticking with the "E" like in First Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check why is happening. Just check is there space in textarea placeholder. second textarea is looking like your textarea because of space given in placeholder.

If you want to move placeholder ahead please apply padding to it.

```css
.first{
  padding:0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="first" placeholder="Enter Address.."></textarea>
<textarea class="second" placeholder=" Enter Address.."></textarea>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please accept and upvote if it helps you. Thank you.

Comment: i already did, but my votes do not count as of now ( not enough reputation).